# converting a random string into date in python raises REdefinition of group name 'm'

Tags: python, string, datetime, parsing, nlp

I have been trying to parse some very old data to structure and store them in a database. I have some random strings that contain dates.

`YEAR:1999        DATE:09/1999`

`DATE:09/1996`

`DATE:1993`

`YEAR:2006   DATE:15/05/06`

`YEAR:2019 DATE:JANUARY 3, 2019`

`YEAR:2019 DATE:FEB. 14, 2019`

`YEAR:2019 DATE: 30/06/2019, JUNE 24, 2019`

as you can see, there's a plethora of possibilities.
I have tried with datetime, dateutil, dateparser and timefhuman to quickly get a date from this.
None, of them had a desired output.
Most success I have had is with dateparser.

```py
    recieving_date = str(row[8])
    try:
      print (recieving_date)
      recieving_date = str(recieving_date.replace("DATE", ''))
      recieving_date = str(recieving_date.replace("YEAR", ''))
      recieving_date = str(recieving_date.replace(":", ''))
      print(recieving_date)
      recieving_date = dateparser.parse(recieving_date, date_formats=["%Y%d/%m/%y", "%Y", "%Y%m/%y" '%d/%m/%Y'])
      print (recieving_date)
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

I get an error **redefinition of group name 'm' as group 5; was group 2 at position 99**
Any suggestions on how to proceed. I thought about reading each character to see if there is a date keyword. That sounds a little to much. There has to be a better way?

Comment: First of all, I would strip the year, completely, as I see no instance, where it's not contained in the rest of the string. In all instances, year comes last, so I would start from the end. Tokenize the input, based on separators and look for the number of tokens. If two, the first is the month, if three you have an additional day info.

Comment: ``` recieving_date = str(recieving_date.replace("DATE", ''))
     recieving_date = str(recieving_date.replace("YEAR", ''))
     recieving_date = str(recieving_date.replace(":", ''))
     recieving_date = str(recieving_date.replace(" ", ''))
     print(recieving_date)
     recieving_date = dateparser.parse(recieving_date, date_formats=['%Y%d/%m/%y', '%Y', '/%Y%m/%y' '%d/%m/%Y'])``` I was trying this but not sure how to pass multiple formats as I get a group error.

Comment: THIS IS THE ERROR redefinition of group name 'm' as group 5; was group 2 at position 100

Comment: what is with your last entry? `YEAR:2019 DATE: 30/06/2019, JUNE 24, 2019` is this one entry?

Comment: Its very random. But yes, something similar. They all have different white spaces.

Comment: No, I mean, what should the output of your last entry be? Is it 30.6.2019 or 24.6.2019? Or should it be two entries? Or a range?

Comment: Ow yeah it's probably typed wrong. I am okay if we discard those logical errors.

Comment: The error your having is because you can't use the same identifier twice, so you have to do some cleanup. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very verbose parser for the format(s) you provided. Output is given as a list of [year, month, day], where each entry is only present if found in the date.

```
import datetime
dates = ['YEAR:1999        DATE:09/1999',
         'DATE:09/1996',
         'DATE:1993 ',
         'YEAR:2006   DATE:15/05/06 ',
         'YEAR:2019 DATE:JANUARY 3, 2019',
         'YEAR:2019 DATE:FEB. 14, 2019 ',
         'YEAR:2019 DATE: 30/06/2019']
output = []
for date in dates:
    year = None
    # getting the year from the 'YEAR:' key.
    if 'YEAR' in date:
        year = int(date.split(' ',1)[0].replace('YEAR:','').strip())
        date = date.split(' ',1)[1].strip()
    #Some string cleaning
    date = date.replace('DATE:','')
    date = date.replace('/',' ').strip().replace(',',' ')
    date = date.split()
    if year is None:
        year = int(date[-1])
    date = date[0:-1]
    if len(date)==0:
        output.append([year])
        continue
    elif len(date)==1:
        month = int(date[0])
        output.append([year, month])
        continue
    else:
        try:
            day = int(date[0])
            month = int(date[1])
            output.append([year, month, day])
        except ValueError:
            day = int(date[1])
            #Getting month number from name
            month = datetime.datetime.strptime(date[0][0:3], '%b').month
            output.append([year, month, day])

print(output)
```

**Update**:

It is possible to get somewhere with dateparser. For your input the code looks like:

```
import dateparser
dates = ['YEAR:1999        DATE:09/1999',
         'DATE:09/1996',
         'DATE:1993 ',
         'YEAR:2006   DATE:15/05/06 ',
         'YEAR:2019 DATE:JANUARY 3, 2019',
         'YEAR:2019 DATE:FEB. 14, 2019 ',
         'YEAR:2019 DATE: 30/06/2019']

for date in dates:
    if 'YEAR' in date:
        date = date.split(' ',1)[1].strip()
    date = date.replace('DATE:','').strip()
    parsed_date = dateparser.parse(date, 
                                   date_formats=['%m/%Y', '%Y', '%d/%m/%Y', ],
                                   languages = ['en'])
    print(parsed_date)
```

but as you see, there will be a month, day, and a time added, which is not given in the input.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work for all cases as the strings above are a sample. What I would like to do is use dateparser.parse() and create a list of expected formats like %Y%d/%m or %Y/%m. I got it to work in some cases. When I use one string. But the description says I can pass a list of expected formats and I get the error on the headline.

Comment: I should Add that I didn't get a chance to properly test it

Comment: The problem I see is, that the logic of dateparser probably will not be enough for this use-case. You'll certainly have to put in some logic somewhere, so I gave this as a starting point.

Comment: I will test yours more.

Comment: But Are there no other ways that I can specify the types of formats my datestring may have? Like I did? or maybe should I run  the parser for each type of format?

Comment: Of course there are. But you might need to do additional cleaning nevertheless.

Comment: dateparser automatically assumes day and month, if not given (same for time of the day), if you don't have that information, the parsed result is wrong.

Comment: Yes this is what I was trying to do. A few questions. How does the date_formats work? at first I was just trying to write whatever the expected input maybe. How come your one had %Y twice? Also you are iterating over YEAR but the DATE keyword is present every where.

Comment: `date_formats` is a list, where each item can be a string, where every group (year, day, month etc.) can only be listed once. So `%Y` is valid, where `%Y:%y` isn't. This is why I cleaned up the input and stripped the year (including the keyword) if present.